# Any pitfalls converting an F# ASP.NET WebAPI application from sync to async one route at a time?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, async-await, f#

We are considering migrating a medium-sized F# ASP.NET WebAPI application running on .NET 6 from sync to async route-by-route. That is, convert one route at a time to async-all-the-way. Are there any pitfalls to this approach?

Embedded in this question, I would like some insight into how threads are managed for async vs. non-async routes. If we were to have sync and async routes living side-by-side in the same ASP.NET process, would they share the same ASP.NET managed thread pool, or would they each have separate thread pools? I am curious if during the transition we would actually end up with greater total number of threads in use.

And to be perfectly clear, I am asking about implementing "traditional" F# `async` computation expressions specifically, not the new `task` computation expressions (though any additional insights there would be welcome too).

Comment: I don't think F# uses the .NET thread pool by default, but you can access it via `Async.SwitchToThreadPool()` if you want. You might find [this article](http://tomasp.net/blog/async-non-blocking-gui.aspx/) helpful, even though it is not aimed at web apps.